# Pick height of CSS position:sticky

Tags: css

I have made an element sticky but I don't arrive in defining the area in which the elements should stay sticky. The current area was not picked by me but was defined automatically when I applied the position:sticky. Obviously I want full control over the space my sticky elements uses as active area, and I want to pick precisely where the element must stop during the scrolling.

The element uses roughly 50% of it's space where it's supposed to stay sticky.

Here is the url in question: https://www.varamedia.be/website-laten-maken/restaurants/

I get my inspiration from the google marketing platform sales page. Here you see the same kind of behaviour I'm trying to replicate: https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/enterprise/

Probably I'm missing something here... Thanks a lot for any kind of help.

I read through SO but did not find a proper answer to this question, hence the new thread.

Here is the custom CSS I added in my WP child theme style.css file:

```
.stickyimage{
    width:100%;
  background:orangered;
  height:0px;
  font-size:24px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:60px;
  /*following codes is for sticky */
  position:sticky;
  top:0; /* it's up to you */
}

body {
    direction: ltr;
    color: #a1a1a1;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 24px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: visible;
    background-position: 0 0;
    letter-spacing: 0.01em;
    word-spacing: 0.01em;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are still struggling with this, I inspected your web page and may have found the problem.

The problem lies in the parent container of `#sidebar`, its `position: relative` causes the unexpected behavior.

To fix this you can overwrite its CSS. To target the parent `div` of `#sidebar` you can simply do:

```
div > #sidebar {
  position: static;
}
```

The code above targets `div` elements which have a `#sidebar` element as child. You can change its `position` to anything but absolute, relative, sticky or fixed. More information on CSS positioning [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

[image: Page inspection screenshot]

The key takeaway here is if you want to dynamically position an element, make sure its parent is statically positioned to avoid unexpected behavior.

Comment: Great insights! Thanks a lot :)